# Efficiently calculate cumulative sum of a multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

If I have a 1D array arr[x]

```
cumulative_arr[x]=cumulative_arr[x-1]+arr[x]
```

For a 2D array arr[x][y]

```
cumulative_arr[x][y]=cumulative_arr[x-1][y]+cumulative_arr[x][y-1]-cumulative_arr[x-1][y-1]+arr[x][y]
```

How do I scale out this method for arrays of larger dimensions?

Cumulative Sum for a 4D array would be:-

```
cumulative_sum[w][x][y][z] = sum of arr[i][j][k][l] for all i<=w,j<=x,k<=y and l<=z.
```

I want to find a method for an N dimensional array.

Comment: Is the code `Python` or `C++`?

Comment: An implementation/abstraction in any would do. I tagged both to make sure I don't come across something else.

Comment: So the question is about finding sum of any rectangle in a large 2D array?

Comment: No, it's about finding the cumulative sum of any multidimensional array. I'll edit the post to include more details

Comment: so, you want to find the N-dimensional recurrence relationship between `cumsum_arr[i, j, k, ...]` and `cumsum_arr[i - 1, j, k, ...]`, `cumsum_arr[i, j - 1, k, ...]`, `cumsum_arr[i, j, k - 1, ...]`, etc. is that correct?

Comment: yeah, because that would solve my problem. any other way to determine the value of cumsum_arr will do as well.

Comment: Looks like you could use a nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged as C++, here we go...

### One dimensional:

```
static const unsigned int ARRAY_CAPACITY = 64u;
int sum = 0;
sum = std::accumulate(&array[0], &array[ARRAY_CAPACITY], 0);
```

### Two dimensional:

```
static const unsigned int MAXIMUM_ROWS = 32u;
static const unsigned int MAXIMUM_COLUMNS = 16u;
int sum = 0;
sum = std::accumulate(&array[0][0], &array[MAXIMUM_ROWS][MAXIMUM_COLUMNS], 0);
```

### Three dimensional (illustrating classical `for` loops):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < CAPACITY_DIMENSION_3; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < CAPACITY_DIMENSION_2; ++y)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < CAPACITY_DIMENSION_1; ++z)
        {
            sum += array[x][y][z];
        }
    }
}
```

If the array slots are contiguous for all dimensions, you could cast the array as single dimension, and sum up as a single dimensional array.

Comment: This calculates the sum for the entire array. I want to find the cumulative sum for an array location. An example would be: cumulative_sum[w][x][y][z] = sum of arr[i][j][k][l] for all i<=w,j<=x,k<=y and l<=z for a 4D array, I want to scale this to even higher dimensions.

Comment: Are you asking for the value in an array at a given location?  Sum usually implies adding more than one value.

Comment: Yeah, Actually I meant the cumulative sum at each location of the array. I provided a make-shift definition of what I wanted in an edit.

Comment: You could just replace `std::accumulate` with `std::partial_sum` (partial sum is the correct terminology, btw), and treat both matrices flatly. I wonder if it is possible to define some kind of elegant `std::begin()` for these types.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a recursive function, like the one below:

```
function dimensionalSum(arr: any[]){
    if(typeof arr[0] == 'number'){
        return arr.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);
    }
    return arr.reduce((acc, dim) => acc + dimensionalSum(dim), 0);
}
```

Note: The example is written in typescript, and it is just a proof of concept.

This way, it does not matter how many dimensions you have.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a way of computing the cumulative sum array over all dimensions of an arbitrary N-dimensional array, then, in Python, you could leverage the power of NumPy's `cumsum()`:

```
import numpy as np


def cumsum_all(arr):
    result = arr
    for i in range(arr.ndim):
        result = np.cumsum(result, i)
    return result
```

Testing this one would get:

```
arr = np.arange((2 * 3)).reshape((2, 3))

print(arr)
# [[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]]

print(cumsum_all(arr))
# [[ 0  1  3]
#  [ 3  8 15]]
```

```
arr = np.arange((2 * 3 * 4)).reshape((2, 3, 4))

print(arr)
# [[[ 0  1  2  3]
#   [ 4  5  6  7]
#   [ 8  9 10 11]]
#  [[12 13 14 15]
#   [16 17 18 19]
#   [20 21 22 23]]]

print(cumsum_all(arr))
# [[[  0   1   3   6]
#   [  4  10  18  28]
#   [ 12  27  45  66]]
#  [[ 12  26  42  60]
#   [ 32  68 108 152]
#   [ 60 126 198 276]]]
```